# View as POPUP in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to show a view(let us call it child view) as a popup on other view(let us call it parent view). The child view will contains images,labels and a button(TO dismiss the childView). I have googled for about an hour or so, but I am not really understanding on how to start the task. Kindly, help me with the approach,solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does this child view need to cover the full screen?

Comment: Yes,child must completely overlap on the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.It will add a subview to your main view along with an animation:

```
       //if you want to set your child view frame to your parent view frame.use this
        self.childview.frame = self.view.frame;
       //if not
        self.childview.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);//ur own frame positon  
self.childview.alpha = 0.0f;
[self.view addSubview:self.childview];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.childview.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }]; 


    ///After this..if you want to remove it.

       [self.childview removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this Demo for your this requirement..

1. [PopupView](https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView)

In this Above demo you can access controls like UIButton ProgressBar,etc in your view from PopUPView This is Best Demo and `SNPopupView` class to use with its delegate method

also this is another demo

2 [alpopoverview](http://www.mobilebricks.com/ios/alpopoverview)